# How to Draw a Rounded Rectangle with WinForms (.NET)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Draw rectangle using C# and I need to draw the arc in every edges first of all I draw rectangle and then I need click button it will draw the arc at edges, how can I do it?

Comment: Best example on internet http://netcode.ru/dotnet/?lang=&katID=30&skatID=283&artID=7833

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The graphics class in C# does not have a built-in method to draw rounded rectangles, however there are several ways that you can accomplish this affect. The links in the answer by [Jay Riggs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967944/draw-rectangle-using-c-and-i-need-to-draw-the-arc-in-every-edges-how-can-i-do/1967958#1967958) offer good suggestions on where to start, additionally I would suggest that you check out this article:

### [C# - Creating Rounded Rectangles Using A Graphics Path](https://web.archive.org/web/20111110163706/http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-creating-rounded-rectangles-using-a-graphics-path)

> So first, we create a GraphicsPath,
>   and then we call StartFigure so that
>   we can start adding edges to the path.
>   The rest of this code is for the top
>   left corner and the top line of the
>   rounded rectangle. If we are supposed
>   to make this corner rounded, we add an
>   arc - otherwise...

Comment: Great link! This helped me out tremendously.

Comment: This link is no longer active and this answer should be modified.

Comment: @TomNeyland, I would check the links in Jay Riggs' answer. I used the code in the first one and it works like a charm!

Comment: This isn't helpful. The link is 404

Comment: Here's a working version of the above link in case anyone else finds this page:  https://web.archive.org/web/20121102092054/http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-creating-rounded-rectangles-using-a-graphics-path

Comment: Don't forget to look at the comment of Luis Dragotto 04/03/2010 - 15:23. In my case I needed to follow his advise to make the result acceptable.

Comment: where do I put the code? I am a beginner in creating c# ui

Answer (score 22):

Draw a rectangle with rounded corners?

Try:

[Extended Graphics - Rounded rectangles, Font metrics and more for C# 3.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ExtendedGraphicsII.aspx)
[Extended Graphics - An implementation of Rounded Rectangle in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ExtendedGraphics.aspx)

Comment: That first link (Rounded rectangles, Font metrics...) is pure gold. Click "download source" to get an awesome set of extension methods off of the Graphics library (e.g. FillRoundedRectangle and DrawRoundedRectangle).  It's a great article, but all you really need is the single .cs file in the download.

Comment: That first link is fantastic! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old, but it's the top hit when searching for how to do rounded rectangles in C# and I've had some problems with it. The AddArc method is inaccurate and as such if you use the code from the accepted answer you will get a funky rounded rectangle. The top left corner is correct, the top right and bottom left are misshapen, and the bottom right is too small. I have adjusted some things in the code to compensate for AddArc's inaccuracies and I believe I have a working solution for creating a proper rounded rectangle. This version can also separate the rectangle into top-left-half and bottom-right-half sections which is handy for doing light/dark shading for 3d effect.

Example usage for setting a window region and also creating topleft/bottomright paths for tracing with light and dark pens for shading:

```
        Region = new Region(RoundedRectangles.RoundedRectangle.Create(new Rectangle(0, 0, Size.Width, Size.Height), 8, RoundedRectangles.RoundedRectangle.RectangleCorners.TopRight | RoundedRectangles.RoundedRectangle.RectangleCorners.TopLeft));
        TopLeftPath = RoundedRectangles.RoundedRectangle.Create(new Rectangle(0, 0, Size.Width, Size.Height), 8, RoundedRectangles.RoundedRectangle.RectangleCorners.TopRight | RoundedRectangles.RoundedRectangle.RectangleCorners.TopLeft, RoundedRectangles.RoundedRectangle.WhichHalf.TopLeft);
        BottomRightPath = RoundedRectangles.RoundedRectangle.Create(new Rectangle(0, 0, Size.Width-1, Size.Height-1), 8, RoundedRectangles.RoundedRectangle.RectangleCorners.TopRight | RoundedRectangles.RoundedRectangle.RectangleCorners.TopLeft, RoundedRectangles.RoundedRectangle.WhichHalf.BottomRight);
```

And finally the code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace RoundedRectangles
{
public abstract class RoundedRectangle
{
    [Flags]
    public enum RectangleCorners
    {
        None = 0, TopLeft = 1, TopRight = 2, BottomLeft = 4, BottomRight = 8,
        All = TopLeft | TopRight | BottomLeft | BottomRight
    }

    public enum WhichHalf
    {
        TopLeft,
        BottomRight,
        Both
    }

    static void Corner(GraphicsPath path, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3)
    {
        path.AddLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        path.AddLine(x2, y2, x3, y3);
    }

    public static GraphicsPath Create(int x, int y, int width, int height, int radius, RectangleCorners corners, WhichHalf half)
    {
        if (radius <= 0)
        {
            GraphicsPath rectp = new GraphicsPath();
            rectp.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
            return rectp;
        }

        int dia = radius * 2;

        Rectangle TLarc = new Rectangle(x, y, dia, dia);
        Rectangle TRarc = new Rectangle(x + width - dia - 1, y, dia, dia);
        Rectangle BRarc = new Rectangle(x + width - dia - 1, y + height - dia - 1, dia, dia);
        Rectangle BLarc = new Rectangle(x, y + height - dia - 1, dia, dia);

        Rectangle TLsquare = new Rectangle(x, y, radius, radius);
        Rectangle TRsquare = new Rectangle(x + width - radius, y, radius, radius);
        Rectangle BRsquare = new Rectangle(x + width - radius, y + height - radius, radius, radius);
        Rectangle BLsquare = new Rectangle(x, y + height - radius, radius, radius);

        GraphicsPath p = new GraphicsPath();
        p.StartFigure();

        if (half == WhichHalf.Both || half == WhichHalf.TopLeft)
        {
            if (corners.HasFlag(RectangleCorners.BottomLeft))
                p.AddArc(BLarc, 135, 45);
            else
                p.AddLine(BLsquare.Left, BLsquare.Bottom, BLsquare.Left, BLsquare.Top);

            p.AddLine(BLsquare.Left, BLsquare.Top - 1, TLsquare.Left, TLsquare.Bottom + 1);

            if (corners.HasFlag(RectangleCorners.TopLeft))
                p.AddArc(TLarc, 180, 90);
            else
                Corner(p, TLsquare.Left, TLsquare.Bottom, TLsquare.Left, TLsquare.Top, TLsquare.Right, TLsquare.Top);

            p.AddLine(TLsquare.Right + 1, TLsquare.Top, TRsquare.Left - 1, TRsquare.Top);

            if (corners.HasFlag(RectangleCorners.TopRight))
                p.AddArc(TRarc, -90, 45);
        }

        if (half == WhichHalf.Both || half == WhichHalf.BottomRight)
        {
            if (corners.HasFlag(RectangleCorners.TopRight))
                p.AddArc(TRarc, -45, 45);
            else
                p.AddLine(TRsquare.Right, TRsquare.Top, TRsquare.Right, TRsquare.Bottom);

            p.AddLine(TRsquare.Right, TRsquare.Bottom + 1, BRsquare.Right, BRsquare.Top - 1);

            if (corners.HasFlag(RectangleCorners.BottomRight))
                p.AddArc(BRarc, 0, 90);
            else
                Corner(p, BRsquare.Right, BRsquare.Top, BRsquare.Right, BRsquare.Bottom, BRsquare.Left, BRsquare.Bottom);

            p.AddLine(BRsquare.Left - 1, BRsquare.Bottom, BLsquare.Right + 1, BLsquare.Bottom);

            if (corners.HasFlag(RectangleCorners.BottomLeft))
                p.AddArc(BLarc, 90, 45);
            else
                p.AddLine(BLsquare.Right, BLsquare.Bottom, BLsquare.Left, BLsquare.Bottom);
        }

        return p;
    }

    public static GraphicsPath Create(Rectangle rect, int radius, RectangleCorners c, WhichHalf which_half)
    { return Create(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height, radius, c, which_half); }

    public static GraphicsPath Create(Rectangle rect, int radius, RectangleCorners c)
    { return Create(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height, radius, c, WhichHalf.Both); }

    public static GraphicsPath Create(Rectangle rect, int radius)
    { return Create(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height, radius, RectangleCorners.All, WhichHalf.Both); }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First draw the four lines, and draw arcs at the 4 corners.

Answer (score 0):

Everything above works for drawing but if you want to convert your graphics path to **custom control**'s region i think you should use **CreateRoundRectRgn** function (from gdi32) for proper curve for top right, bottom left and bottom right edges (top left edge has been drawn correctly according to radius). Take a quick look at http://pages.citebite.com/e1u2t5b7t4bih (site from instanceofTom's answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use the LineJoin property of Pen

```
Pen myPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);

myPen.Width = 8.0f;

// Set the LineJoin property
myPen.LineJoin = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineJoin.Round;

// Draw the rectangle
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, new Rectangle(50, 50, 200, 200));
```