# C# Form with custom border and rounded edges

Tags: c#, winforms, rounded-corners, formborderstyle

I am using this code to make my form (FormBorderStyle=none) with rounded edges:

```
[DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
(
    int nLeftRect, // x-coordinate of upper-left corner
    int nTopRect, // y-coordinate of upper-left corner
    int nRightRect, // x-coordinate of lower-right corner
    int nBottomRect, // y-coordinate of lower-right corner
    int nWidthEllipse, // height of ellipse
    int nHeightEllipse // width of ellipse
 );

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, 20, 20));
}
```

And this to set a custom border on the Paint event:

```
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle, Color.Black, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, Color.Black, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, Color.Black, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, Color.Black, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
```

But see this [image: screenshot].

The inside form rectangle doesn't have rounded edges.

How can I make the blue inside form rectangle to have rounded edge too so it wont look like the screenshot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Region propery simply cuts off the corners. To have a true rounded corner you will have to draw the rounded rectangles.

[Drawing rounded rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967944/how-to-draw-a-rounded-rectangle-with-winforms-net)

It might be easier to draw an image of the shape you want and put that on the transparent form. Easier to draw but cannot be resized.

Answer (score 0):

Note you're leaking the handle returned by [CreateRoundRectRgn()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183516.aspx), you should free it with [DeleteObject()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183539.aspx) after it is used.

The Region.FromHrgn() copies the definition, so it won't free the handle.

```
[DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    IntPtr handle = CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, 20, 20);
    if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        ; // error with CreateRoundRectRgn
    Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(handle);
    DeleteObject(handle);
}
```

*(would add as comment but reputation is ded)*