# Form with Rounded Borders in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010, formborderstyle

I am using this code to make the form have no border style:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

I need to make rounded edges on the form.

Is there an easy way? How do I do it?

Comment: The answer to this question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092216/c-sharp-form-with-custom-border-and-rounded-edges

Comment: That looks great, but um...i am new so...i have no idea where to put all that stuff. I know where to put the code under the form() thing, but the other is hard. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx

The Form class inherits from the Control class, so try doing the same sample that you have on the link to the **Form's Region property** (and do it on the form event of course):

```
    // This method will change the square button to a circular button by 
// creating a new circle-shaped GraphicsPath object and setting it 
// to the RoundButton objects region.
private void roundButton_Paint(object sender, 
    System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{

    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath buttonPath = 
        new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();

    // Set a new rectangle to the same size as the button's 
    // ClientRectangle property.
    System.Drawing.Rectangle newRectangle = roundButton.ClientRectangle;

    // Decrease the size of the rectangle.
    newRectangle.Inflate(-10, -10);

    // Draw the button's border.
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, newRectangle);

    // Increase the size of the rectangle to include the border.
    newRectangle.Inflate( 1,  1);

    // Create a circle within the new rectangle.
    buttonPath.AddEllipse(newRectangle);

    // Set the button's Region property to the newly created 
    // circle region.
    roundButton.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(buttonPath);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the question was already answered, I would like to add an alternative and silly BUT a not really recommended practice since your question does not restrict the answer into being codes...

- Create a blank, square image with your background color as fill, then erase the top-left rounded corners to be transparent, repeat this to all corners
- Set a very unlikely color as your form background color
- Set this color as the `TransparencyKey` on your form
- Add the images as `PictureBox` and put them to the corresponding corners

*Viola!*

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void RoundBorderForm(Form frm)
    {

        Rectangle Bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, frm.Width, frm.Height);
        int CornerRadius = 20;
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        path.AddArc(Bounds.X, Bounds.Y, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 180, 90);
        path.AddArc(Bounds.X + Bounds.Width - CornerRadius, Bounds.Y, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 270, 90);
        path.AddArc(Bounds.X + Bounds.Width - CornerRadius, Bounds.Y + Bounds.Height - CornerRadius, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 0, 90);
        path.AddArc(Bounds.X, Bounds.Y + Bounds.Height - CornerRadius, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 90, 90);
        path.CloseAllFigures();

        frm.Region = new Region(path);
        frm.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide context for why this solves the OP's problem; Code should never substitute for words! Also, thanks for contributing to [so].