# Rounded Corners in C# windows forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a window without borders. I searched net for rounded corners but all with borders. How can i make rounded corners of the form`(not with borders)` ? Is there a way to do that?

I am a newbie to c#, so please  explain...

Thanks

Answer (score 69, accepted):

try this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
        (
            int nLeftRect,     // x-coordinate of upper-left corner
            int nTopRect,      // y-coordinate of upper-left corner
            int nRightRect,    // x-coordinate of lower-right corner
            int nBottomRect,   // y-coordinate of lower-right corner
            int nWidthEllipse, // width of ellipse
            int nHeightEllipse // height of ellipse
        );

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, 20, 20));
        }
    }
}
```

from here: [Form with Rounded Borders in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674228/form-with-rounded-borders-in-c)

Comment: Note that Width and Height are references to this.Width and this.Height.

Comment: Tried using this on a Panel. It only rounds one of the edges (top left)!

Comment: @ElMac: I not try it again and it works for me great. could you verify you copy-paste the code correct please?

Comment: I found the problem. If I make the Panel too small, some edges get cut off. I don't know the reason yet, but I can't use this approach because the panels I use should be almost button-sized.

Comment: You may also need to add "this.AllowTransparency = true;"

Comment: the reason for cut corners is that the region is not resized with the window, you need to recreate it and reasign it on resize

Answer (score 2):

The Region propery simply cuts off the corners. To have a true rounded corner you will have to draw the rounded rectangles.

[Drawing rounded rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967944/how-to-draw-a-rounded-rectangle-with-winforms-net)

It might be easier to draw an image of the shape you want and put that on the transparent form. Easier to draw but cannot be resized.

Also check this [Another One](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ac288404-c5d4-4511-828c-d9e1e0fb05c7/how-to-give-a-c-windows-forms-application-rounded-corners)

Comment: "The Region propery [SIC] simply cuts off the corners." This is true, it clips the rendering of the form making the corners of the form have rounded transparent corners.  In order to *draw* rounded corners, say with a 3D bevel appearance, additional drawing work is required.  So you're not wrong, but I thought your phrasing was a just a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I found this code

To come up with the rounded corners textbox, I started trying to work with the paint override event, but unfortunately without any result, which is due to the fact (I assume) that the textbox is derived from Windows. Therefore, I tried overriding the WM_PAINT API instead, which had the desired results

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17453/Textbox-with-rounded-corners

Thanks