# How to Change WinForms titleBar color?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to change color of Title bar of Windows Form as I have highlighted below in Image

[image]

You can see in this pic, marked area is White in Color , normally it's color is sky blue and it's corners are not round as we have in Windows form. So my Question is how can I change color of Title bar, color of Form Border and it's corner not round.

I know using third party control like infragistics I can achieve this. But i want to do it myself. I have seen a demo on codeproject few months ago but i am unable to find it again.

Comment: That is Github client. IIRC, it is written in WPF not Winforms.

Comment: You can override the ncpaint event, but its normally derived from windows theme

Comment: @fahadash, It may be in WPF but I have just finished a project and i have done it using infragistic control. So it may be possible in Windows form somehow ?

Comment: A window's title bar color is a system setting, chosen by the user when he picks his preferred theme.  Programs like this create their custom title bar by starting with a borderless window and just painting it.  And a whole bunch of code to restore lost functionality.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel The link which you have mentioned is explaining about title, border color but it's not explaining how i can remove round corner

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822067/rounded-corners-in-c-sharp-windows-forms) will help