# Change style of datetimepicker in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to change the style of datetime picker in windows c# application, I want round shape border to my calendar. Required style and current view is provided in Image . Thank you. [image]

Comment: Yes, paint it yourself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822067/rounded-corners-in-c-sharp-windows-forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Syncfusion DateTimePickerAdv](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-forms/datetimepickeradv) supports creating rounded corner DateTimePicker. Here is an [example](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SyncfusionDateTimePickerAdv-806808476.zip).

**Screenshot**

[image]

You need Syncfusion Essential Studio to be installed for the sample to work.
The entire product is available in this [link](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/evalconfirmation).

**Note:** I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No

Long answer: You can't do that 'out of the box' in win forms application, unless you are ready to pull your hair out to write custom controls (Even then you will not achieve what you are expecting, like above image)
Other options would be to use WPF and/or use some 3rd party controls (like Telerik or Syncfusion)