# Ceating Floating Widget/Gadget

Tags: c#, windows, widget, startup, floating

I am trying to create a GUI Windows Software with C# that gives updates to the user by the uses of a floating widget on on the Desktop screen.

I needed help on how you can create an Windows Application that runs at Startup and shows a Desktop widget.

Below is Screenshot example of what I mean by 'floating widget', because am not sure what it is really called.

[image: Screenshot showing 'Floating widget"]

Comment: You can set the FormBorderStyle property to None and implement a moving behavior (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592876/make-a-borderless-form-movable). Assuming that you are using Windows Forms.

Comment: @PhilippApe Thank you for your Answer, However I am not asking how to create A borderless FormBorderStyle. I want to create a program that

1. Starts automatically after log in
2. and shows a floating widget on the desktop as shown by the screenshot.

Comment: For 1. please try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089601/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-application-at-windows-startup and for 2. this could be a valid starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822067/rounded-corners-in-c-sharp-windows-forms . Drag support is already covered in my last reference posted.