# Adding a border color on a form in visual C#

Tags: c#, border, visual-c#-express-2010

Ok, i have made a form with this code: `this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;` Ok, i have also added a border radius with this code:

```
[DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
    (
        int nLeftRect, // x-coordinate of upper-left corner
        int nTopRect, // y-coordinate of upper-left corner
        int nRightRect, // x-coordinate of lower-right corner
        int nBottomRect, // y-coordinate of lower-right corner
        int nWidthEllipse, // height of ellipse
        int nHeightEllipse // width of ellipse
     );

    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, 20, 20));
    }
```

So, what i need is the add a small black border around the form that curves with the border-radius. How do i do that?

Ok, i added this, it works, but it does not go with the border, it just goes strait: `e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1));`
and this:

```
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Form with custom border and rounded edges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092216/c-sharp-form-with-custom-border-and-rounded-edges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the form's OnPaintBackground() method and simply draw the border with the Graphics methods, using the passed e.Graphics object.

Note that you don't have to pinvoke when you use the Region(GraphicsPath) constructor.  That same GraphicsPath will also be handy to draw the border.

Comment: i have tried *e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1));* but the border is only on the top and the left side. Also, the borders do not curve with the form. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Clearly you can't use DrawRectangle when your form is not a rectangle :)  Use ClientSize.Width/Height and either subtract 2 or add 1 to the CreateRoundRectRgn() call.

Comment: Ok, i have been looking and looking and looking, but i can not find anything...can you help me?

Comment: I don't get the problem.  You don't know how to use Graphics.DrawLine and Graphics.DrawEllipse?  Don't expect only one line of code, you have to write more of them.  4 lines and 4 arcs.  That's normal when you create a non-standard UI, it is more work.

Comment: no, i am only 15, and i am leaning, so i really have not used the draw event much...

Comment: Well, you got another 7 years before it starts to become important.  So experiment away and see what these drawing methods do.  Once you got that, experiment with the GraphicsPath class.