# C# Non-rectangular pictureboxes

Tags: c#, transparency, picturebox

Is there a way to create non-rectangular pictureBoxes. I have round shapes that should overlap and if possible should be in different pictureboxes..
I tried the [this here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150110170901/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/library/aa289517(v=vs.71).aspx), but you could not see both pictureboxes that are overlapping at a time, but just one..

Here the picture that resulted from my tests:
[image: IMG]

Comment: Don't use any controls.  Try drawing straight into your container-- make sure it's double-buffered.

Comment: I guess you could use GraphicPath to "crop" your pictureboxes by creating a custom transparent mask. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967944/how-to-draw-a-rounded-rectangle-with-winforms-net

Comment: It's doable using [path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you're using WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the PictureBoxes circular by adding an Ellipse to a GraphicsPath and then building a new Region from it.

Here's a quick example:

```
public class Target : PictureBox
{
    public Target()
    {
        this.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        this.Paint += Target_Paint;
        Rectangle rc = this.ClientRectangle;
        rc.Inflate(-10, -10);
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        gp.AddEllipse(rc);
        this.Region = new Region(gp);
    }

    void Target_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rc = this.ClientRectangle;
        rc.Inflate(-10, -10);
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 5))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, rc);
        }
        rc = new Rectangle(new Point(this.Size.Width / 2, this.Size.Height / 2), new Size(1, 1));
        rc.Inflate(9, 9);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, rc);
    }
}
```

After compiling, the new control appears at the top of your ToolBox.

Here's a screenshot with three of them overlapping each other:
[image]