# How can I draw a rounded rectangle as the border for a rounded Form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, rounded-corners

I'm creating a Form that has a rounded border (as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092216/c-sharp-form-with-custom-border-and-rounded-edges)).
As this person also seems to have an issue with, I can't seem to draw a rounded border.

This is code I have used for setting up the actual border shape:

```c
// ... within InitializeComponent ...
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
IntPtr handle = CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, 20, 20);
Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(handle);
DeleteObject(handle);

this.ResizeRedraw = true;
```

This is code that overrides `OnPaint` and draws the border outline.

```c
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
     // I've tried modifying the parameters here.
     GraphicsPath path = MyRoundedRectangle.Create(0, 0, Width, Height, 10, MyRoundedRectangle.RectangleCorners.All);

     Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 3f);
     e.Graphics.DrawPath(p, path);
}
```

The content of `MyRoundedRectangle` is identical to the code provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967944/how-to-draw-a-rounded-rectangle-with-winforms-net), in which the answer linked to [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20111110163706/http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-creating-rounded-rectangles-using-a-graphics-path), which contains the code for `MyRoundedRectangle`.

I'd like to have a full surrounding border, but instead I get this: [image: this]

Comment: I think you can use a transparent Form (setting its `TransparencyKey` = `BackColor`, a color to choose wisely: not red-ish, for example), then use `GraphicsPath.AddArc()` to draw the rounded background and a Border, if required. You could take the example here: [How to avoid visual artifacts of colored border of zoomable UserControl with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794097/7444103). It's even easier with a Form (transparency works quite well).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A base implementation of what is described in the comments.
The Form **`frmRoundCorners`** provides some properties that allow to draw its rounded area with a custom BackColor, a custom BorderColor and a custom inner border color, acting as a *shadow* for the internal side of the Form's border.

The Form itself is implemented using a base class, **`baseForm`**, derived from `Form`, so the Form's properties can be set in the Form designer.

The transparency is activated setting the Form's original BackColor equal to its **`TrasparencyKey`**, making its `ClientArea` completely transparent, but drawable.
The Form's original border is set to **`FormBorderStyle.None`** in the base class constructor.
I didn't set a specific `BackColor/TransparencyKey` Color (it must be set in the Form's designer) because I think it's something one need to experiment with. I'd suggest a medium gray color. Avoid **red** components.

The Form can be moved, clicking on any point of its `ClientArea` and dragging it.

The minimum/maximum curvature of the Form and its custom Border is set to `15` and `180` degrees. It cannot be changed to a different range using the PropertyGrid.
The rounded area of the Form and its border are drawn using the [GraphicsPath.AddArc()](http://GraphicsPath.AddArc) method, then applying a [Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix) transformation to the `Graphics` object, both in the `Scale` and the `Transform` (position) components. The `Size` component is untouched.

This is what it looks like:

[image: Rounded draggable borderless Form]

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[ToolboxItem(false)]
public partial class frmRoundCorners : baseForm
{
    private GraphicsPath pathRegion = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Winding);
    private GraphicsPath pathBorder;
    Point pMousePosition = Point.Empty;

    public frmRoundCorners()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                 ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                 ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                 ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
            pMousePosition = e.Location;
        }
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
            Point screenPos = PointToScreen(e.Location);
            this.Location = new Point(screenPos.X - pMousePosition.X, screenPos.Y - pMousePosition.Y);
        }
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
        RoundedCornerRectangle(ClientRectangle);
        RectangleF rect = pathRegion.GetBounds();
        float scaleX = 1 - (BorderSize / rect.Width);
        float scaleY = 1 - (BorderSize / rect.Height);
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(BorderColor, BorderSize))
        using (Pen penBorder = new Pen(InternalBorderColor, 2))
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(FillColor))
        using (var mx = new Matrix(scaleX, 0, 0, scaleY, (pen.Width / 2), (pen.Width / 2)))
        {
            e.Graphics.Transform = mx;
            e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, pathRegion);
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(penBorder, pathBorder);
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, pathRegion);
        }
    }

    private void RoundedCornerRectangle(Rectangle r)
    {
        pathRegion = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Alternate);
        float innerCurve = CurveAngle - m_PenSizeOffset;

        pathRegion.StartFigure();
        pathRegion.AddArc(r.X, r.Y, CurveAngle, CurveAngle, 180, 90);
        pathRegion.AddArc(r.Right - CurveAngle, r.Y, CurveAngle, CurveAngle, 270, 90);
        pathRegion.AddArc(r.Right - CurveAngle, r.Bottom - CurveAngle, CurveAngle, CurveAngle, 0, 90);
        pathRegion.AddArc(r.X, r.Bottom - CurveAngle, CurveAngle, CurveAngle, 90, 90);
        pathRegion.CloseFigure();

        pathBorder = new GraphicsPath();
        pathBorder.StartFigure();
        pathBorder.AddArc(r.X + m_PenSizeOffset, r.Y + m_PenSizeOffset, innerCurve, innerCurve, 180, 90);
        pathBorder.AddArc(r.Right - innerCurve - m_PenSizeOffset, r.Y + m_PenSizeOffset, innerCurve, innerCurve, 270, 90);
        pathBorder.AddArc(r.Right - innerCurve - m_PenSizeOffset, r.Bottom - innerCurve- m_PenSizeOffset, innerCurve, innerCurve, 0, 90);
        pathBorder.AddArc(r.X + m_PenSizeOffset, r.Bottom - innerCurve - m_PenSizeOffset, innerCurve, innerCurve, 90, 90);
        pathBorder.CloseFigure();
    }
}
```

**`baseForm` class:**

```
public class baseForm : Form
{
    private Color m_InternalBorderColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 128);
    private Color m_BorderColor = Color.Red;
    private Color m_FillColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
    private float m_PenSize = 6f;
    private float m_CurveAngle = 60.0f;
    internal float m_PenSizeOffset = 3f;

    public baseForm() => InitializeComponent();
    private void InitializeComponent() => FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(true), Category("Appearance")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [DefaultValue(60.0f)]
    public virtual float CurveAngle
    {
        get => m_CurveAngle;
        set {
            m_CurveAngle = Math.Max(Math.Min(value, 180), 15);
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(true), Category("Appearance")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [DefaultValue(6.0f)]
    public virtual float BorderSize
    {
        get => m_PenSize;
        set {
            m_PenSize = value;
            m_PenSizeOffset = value / 2.0f;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(true), Category("Appearance")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public virtual Color BorderColor
    {
        get => m_BorderColor;
        set {
            m_BorderColor = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(true), Category("Appearance")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public virtual Color FillColor
    {
        get => m_FillColor;
        set {
            m_FillColor = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(true), Category("Appearance")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [Description("Get or Set the Color of the internal border")]
    public virtual Color InternalBorderColor
    {
        get => m_InternalBorderColor;
        set {
            m_InternalBorderColor = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [DefaultValue(FormBorderStyle.None)]
    public new FormBorderStyle FormBorderStyle
    {
        get => base.FormBorderStyle;
        set => base.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for something similar to this. Thanks!